# How to use WKExtendedRuntimeSession() for background task in watchkit?

Tags: runtime, watchkit, background-task

I am following Apple's article https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions, using "Physical therapy" session, but my task pauses each time the watch face turns off and continues when it's on. Has anyone successfully implemented extended runtime sessions?

Comment: Did you see a white runner glyph on your watch after you do a session.start()?  I'm also struggling with WKExtendedRuntimeSession, but the session seems to work for 1 hr. But stops completely after that.

Comment: Yes, I can see the runner glyph but my task is not executed. The session is supposed to terminate after 1 hr if you select "Physical therapy" or "Mindfulness", according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions).

Comment: The session.start must be called when the app is active. Meaning the app is still showing on the screen. I call session.start() in the applicationDidBecomeActive function. Please post code.